# How to fix ' I have author & book schema, In Postman result, I want to show two or more author for a book'

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, model, mongoose-schema

I want to postman result like this

```
[{
 title:
 year:
 rating:
 authors: [{
    name: 
    birthday:
    country: 
  }]
}]
```

i want two or more author, but I got only one author

```
 model/book.js

  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const authorSchema = require('../models/author');


 const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title:{
       type:String,
       required:true,
       min: 5,
       max: 50
   },
   rating:{
       type: Number,
       required: true,
       min:0,
       max:10
   },
   authors: {
       type: authorSchema,
       required: true
   },

 });
   const Book= new mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);



route/book.js

router.get('/', async(req, res)=>{
    const books= await Book
    .find({}, { _id:0, __v:0 })
     res.send(books);
});  

router.post('/', async(req, res)=>{
const author = await Author.findById  (req.body.authorId);
if(!author) return res.status(400).send('Invalid Author');

let book= new Book({
    title: req.body.title,
    rating: req.body.rating,
    authors:[{
        name: author.name,
        birthday: author.birthday,
        country: author.country
    }]
});

book= await book.save();
res.send(book)

});
module.exports =router;
```

I enter this by POST Method in postman
     {
       "title": "Learn Python",
       "rating": "9",
        "authorId":  [ "5d99ac95f17917117068631b", 
                   "5d99ad75c4edd61f98af740b"]
     }

then I get Only first author, author array not show

Comment: what does 'authorSchema' look like?

Comment: const authorSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 5,
        max:50
    },
    birthday:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    country:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
   
 
});

const Author = new mongoose.model('Author ', authorSchema);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[findById](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) finds a single document by provided _id field

Use [find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) with [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to match the number of documents with an array of _id.

`Author.find({ $in: req.body.authorId })` will give you an array of authors matched with with `req.body.authorId`.

and then create an author array by looping over the result from `find` query for your `new Book` instance.

**Suggestion**

Use only the fields you require from a `find` query - eg `Author.find({ $in: req.body.authorId }, 'name birthday country')`,

also, if you have a another collection of `Author`, it is better to keep the reference(_id) in `Book` collection instead of passing author details, this will remove the data redundancy from you collections.
You can find out more about data modelling in mongodb [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/)

Comment: I am new in node.js, I could not understand how to create an author array by looping over the result.

Comment: you can do something like this 
`let authorList = authors.map((author) => ({
       name: author.name,
        birthday: author.birthday,
        country: author.country
}))`

and use this authorList in `new Book` instance